My Radio Buttons Are Grouped on the Same Line (Left, Middle, Right). I Clicked The Label for the Second Radio Button and the First One is Selected
I have three radio buttons, all on the same name. When I clicked the first one, it selects the first on. When I click the second one (Need to click the bubble), it selects the second one. When I clicked the third one (Need to also click the bubble), it selects the third one. BUT, if I clicked the label for the second or third one, it automatically selects the first one.
Code:

HTML

                    <div id="Div_For_All_Players"> {/* DIV for all players */}
                        <div id="Div_For_First_Player">
                            <input name="Player_Playing" type="radio" value="One_Player" id="Radio_1" className="Radio_Buttons" onClick={Player_One_Clicked}></input>{/* Radio Buttons for How Many Players */}
                            <label htmlFor="Radio_1" id="Label_1" className="First_Button">One Player</label>{/* Labels for One Player */}
                        </div>

                        <div id="Div_For_Second_Player">
                            <input name="Player_Playing" type="radio" value="Two_Players" id="Radio_2" className="Radio_Buttons" onClick={Player_Two_Clicked}></input>{/* Radio Buttons for How Many Players */}
                            <label htmlFor="Radio_1" id="Label_2" className="Second_Button">Two Players</label>{/* Labels for Two Players */}
                        </div>

                        <div id="Div_For_Third_Player">
                            <input name="Player_Playing" type="radio" value="Three_Players" id="Radio_3" className="Radio_Buttons" onClick={Player_Three_Clicked} defaultChecked={true}></input>{/* Radio Buttons for How Many Players */}
                            <label htmlFor="Radio_1" id="Radio_3_label" className="Third_Button">Three Players</label>{/* Label for Three Players */}
                        </div>
                    </div>

CSS:
#Div_For_First_Player {
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -20px;
  width: 100px;
}
#Div_For_Second_Player {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
#Div_For_Third_Player {
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  float: right;
}

I tried to change the width of the first one to 100px so the div isn't as much
Here's a link to a video I made showcasing the problem: https://imgur.com/a/MqbGXas

Your label's for attribute should have the same value and your input's name attribute. That's how they associate with each other.

They do have the same value. When I click the second one, it does cancel the first one and selects the second one. However, when I click the LABEL for the second one, it goes to the first one. Is there a way I can send a video? (I'm new to Stack, sorry if this question isn't bright).

"Player_Playing" and "Radio_1" are not the same value. :-) Make sure to have a different name for each input, too.

HOLY SHIT, I see it now! I thought you meant each of my for's and name should be the same with each radio button. I got it, and it's working now! Thank you very much!

First,  is a self-closing tag, so you don't need a  closing tag to close it. HTML comments are written as  and not with /* */ (for CSS and other languages). Make sure that the "for" attribute of a label tag matches the input tag's name attribute and that the three input elements have the same name attribute for the radio buttons to work.
New HTML code:
<div id="Div_For_All_Players">
    <!-- DIV for all players -->
    <div id="Div_For_First_Player">
        <input name="Player_Playing" type="radio" value="One_Player" id="Player_Playing" className="Radio_Buttons"
        onClick="{Player_One_Clicked}" />
        <!-- Radio Buttons for How Many Players -->
        <label htmlFor="Player_Playing" id="Label_1" className="First_Button">One
        Player</label><!-- Labels for One Player -->
    </div>

    <div id="Div_For_Second_Player">
        <input name="Player_Playing" type="radio" value="Two_Players" id="Radio_2" className="Radio_Buttons"
        onClick="{Player_Two_Clicked}" />
        <!-- Radio Buttons for How Many Players -->
        <label htmlFor="Player_Playing" id="Label_2" className="Second_Button">Two
        Players</label><!-- Labels for Two Players -->
    </div>

    <div id="Div_For_Third_Player">
        <input name="Player_Playing" type="radio" value="Three_Players" id="Radio_3" className="Radio_Buttons"
        onClick="{Player_Three_Clicked}" defaultChecked="{true}" /><!-- Radio Buttons for How Many Players -->
        <label htmlFor="Player_Playing" id="Radio_3_label" className="Third_Button">Three Players</label>
        <!-- Label for Three Players -->
    </div>


I'm using React code, so my HTML code is JavaScript Syntax Extension. The <!-- comments will not work. I'll need to add "{" in the beginning of /* so those comments work. Also, I tried this code and the problem still persists. Thank you for trying though. Is there a way I can add a video? (I'm new to Stack, sorry if this question isn't bright)
